# Regular expression validator for Date(yyyy/MM/dd) or year(yyyy)

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I want regular validation expression to validate that only year (yyyy) or date is  entered (yyyy-MM-dd).

It must not accept:

```
21,
23323
```

It should accept any four digit integer value (say 2012) and it should also accept year (yyyy-MM-dd) format only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for that.

I would use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `string[]` as a parameter.

```
string s = "2012";
DateTime dt;
var formats = new[] {"yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Your string is a valid DateTime for yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd format.
}
```

You said `yyyy-MM-dd` in your question but you said `yyyy/MM/dd` in your title. Add them to your `formats` array which one you try to validate.