# Regular Expression for yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, date

I have a regular expression in asp.net to check the input data match the format yyyy-MM-dd. But, it always show "Please enter a valid date" if the input data is even valid date. I have tried some regular expressions, but those are also not working.

In aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateFrom" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="DateFrom_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="IMAGES/icon-calendar.png" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="DateFrom_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="DateFrom" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" PopupButtonID="Image1" />
<br /><asp:Label ID="DateFromMsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

In aspx.cs file

```
protected void DateFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string regExp = @"/^((19|20)\d\d+)-(0[1-9]|1[012]+)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/";
        if(!Regex.IsMatch(DateFrom.Text, regExp))
        {
            DateFromMsg.Visible = true;
            DateFromMsg.Text = "Please enter a valid date";
            return;
        }
        BindData();
    }
```

Note: My question is similar as this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239288/regular-expression-validator-for-dateyyyy-mm-dd-or-yearyyyy)
I am sorry for duplicating questions because I really did not notice it and I found the solutions using Regular Expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `DateTime` parsing instead of regex. And I *strongly* suspect you try to use `MM` specifier instead of `mm`. Because `mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for months.

Also based on your regex, you try check your `DateTime` in 20th century or 21st century, you can check it's [`Year` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx) with these century boundaries.

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(DateFrom.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    if(dt.Year >= 1900 && dt.Year <= 2099)
    {
        // Your text is valid.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice answer!!! It really works for me.